# mathdesign fails with font error

Tags: fonts, mathdesign

I have mathdesign installed with texlive 2013. Nothing special about the installation, at least mathdesign or its fonts are not installed by myself.

Everything worked half year ago, but latest updates now cause an error with this code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Here's the output of `\listfiles`

```
 *File List*
 minimal.cls    2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
mathdesign.sty    2013/08/29 v2.31 Math Design Project
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   mdbch.cfg
   mdbch.sty    2013/08/29 v2.31 bitstream bitstream charter + mdbch (Math Design Project)
  mdfont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
mdsffont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
mdttfont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
ot1mdbch.fd    2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mdbch.
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 t1mdbch.fd    2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/mdbch.
  mdacmr.fd
  mdbcmr.fd
```

The error is this one

```
name = md-chr8y, rootname = md-chr8y, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

Cannot find font md-chr8y in map file(s).

kpathsea: Running mktexmf md-chr8y.mf The command name is C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\mktexmf Cannot find md-chr8y.mf . I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf. ps2pk cannot be used. I try gsftopk. gsftopk.exe md-chr8y 576 gsftopk cannot be used. Next I try ttf2pk. ttf2pk.exe -q md-chr8y 576 ttf2pk failed. Finally I try hbf2gf. hbf2gf.exe -q -p md-chr8y 576 All trials failed. kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+576/600 --dpi 576 md-chr8y The command name is C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\mktexpk kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file md-chr8y): Font md-chr8y at 576 not found

 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What can I do to solve this font problem?

Log files:

**missfont.log**

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+576/600 --dpi 576 md-chr8y
```

**complete log file**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2014.1.16)  18 JAN 2014 13:41
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"fontsample - Charter-Bera Sans-Luxi Mono.tex"
(./fontsample - Charter-Bera Sans-Luxi Mono.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mathdesign.sty
Package: mathdesign 2013/08/29 v2.31 Math Design Project

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/mdbch.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/mdbch.sty
Package: mdbch 2013/08/29 v2.31 bitstream bitstream charter + mdbch (Math Desig
n Project)

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdfont.def
File: mdfont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdsffont.def
File: mdsffont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdttfont.def
File: mdttfont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
)
\symmdcal=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mdcal' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 97.
\symmdscr=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mdscr' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 103.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/xmdeuf/m/n --> U/xmdeuf/b/n on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/mdbch/m/n on input line 121.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/mdbch/m/it on input line 122.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/m/n on input line 123.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/mdbch/m/n on input line 124.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/mdbch/b/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/mdbch/b/it on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/mdbch/b/n on input line 129.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/mdbch/m/n --> OT1/mdbch/m/n on input line 131.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/mdbch/b/n on input line 132.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/mdbch/m/it on input line 133.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/cmss/m/n on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/cmtt/m/n on input line 135.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/mdbch/b/n --> OT1/mdbch/b/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/mdbch/b/n on input line 138.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/mdbch/b/it on input line 139.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/cmss/b/n on input line 140.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/cmtt/b/n on input line 141.
\symlettersupright=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersupright' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/mdbch/m/n --> OML/mdbch/b/n on input line 144.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 145.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathcal' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/m/n on input line 167.

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16
\XKV@depth=\count79
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+mdbch on input line 18
6.

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/ot1mdbch.fd
File: ot1mdbch.fd 2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mdbch.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/mdbch/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.60007pt on input line 186.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 449.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 450.
\symmathdesignA=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mathdesignA' in version `bold'
(Font)                  MDA/mdbch/m/n --> MDA/mdbch/b/n on input line 491.
\symmathdesignB=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mathdesignB' in version `bold'
(Font)                  MDB/mdbch/m/n --> MDB/mdbch/b/n on input line 498.
\@emptytoks=\toks17
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 532.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 533.
\rulethickness=\skip41
)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+mdbch on input line 100
.

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/t1mdbch.fd
File: t1mdbch.fd 2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/mdbch.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/mdbch/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.60007pt on input line 100.
))
(./fontsample - Charter-Bera Sans-Luxi Mono.aux)
\openout1 = `"fontsample - Charter-Bera Sans-Luxi Mono.aux"'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for MDA/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for MDA+cmr on input line 4.

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdacmr.fd
File: mdacmr.fd 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for MDB/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for MDB+cmr on input line 4.

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbcmr.fd
File: mdbcmr.fd 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
 [1{c:/Users/Matthias Pospiech/.texlive2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/p
dftex.map}]
(./fontsample - Charter-Bera Sans-Luxi Mono.aux)

 *File List*
 minimal.cls    2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
mathdesign.sty    2013/08/29 v2.31 Math Design Project
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   mdbch.cfg
   mdbch.sty    2013/08/29 v2.31 bitstream bitstream charter + mdbch (Math Desi
gn Project)
  mdfont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
mdsffont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
mdttfont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
ot1mdbch.fd    2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mdbch.
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 t1mdbch.fd    2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/mdbch.
  mdacmr.fd    
  mdbcmr.fd    
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1615 strings out of 493308
 22205 string characters out of 6141367
 59673 words of memory out of 5000000
 5109 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6898 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,4n,29p,279b,98s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file md-chr8y): Font md-chr8y at 576 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: It seems that an entry in the map file is missing. Check whether you have the line `Map mdbch.map` in the file `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\web2c\updmap.cfg`

Comment: Yes there is a line `Map mdbch.map` in that file. There is also a line `md-chr8y CharterBT-Roman " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bchr8a.pfb` in the file `pdftex.map` and `bchr8a.pfb` exists.

Comment: Please, check the path recorded in the `log` file of `pdftex.map`

Comment: `pdftex.map` is located at `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-var\fonts\map\pdftex\updmap` However no log file is there.

Comment: I meant the log file relative to the file you're trying to compile. Search for `pdftex.map`.

Comment: I added the complete log file. But I have no clue what kind of log file should be created and where it should be located by `pdftex.map`.

Comment: The problem is in `c:/Users/Matthias Pospiech/.texlive2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`, as I suspected. You have a personal map file that hasn't been updated. Rename it and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed the file `c:/Users/Matthias Pospiech/.texlive2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` and ran `updmap-sys` and `updmap`. The latter recreated the file `pdftex.map`. The font worked after that again.

Answer (score 0):

texnansi.enc is now missing from fonts/enc/dvips/base where it was in previous versions, copy it back and it will work

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  As it stands this more a comment than an answer.  Where is this file to be found?